# I need to color each second letter from a string in red jquery from a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if could you help me, i am trying to color each second letter from a string from a input.
My code is:

from html:

```
  <input type="text" id="textValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Scrieti Text">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="afisare">Afisati</button>
            <div id="raspuns"></div>
```

from script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        function makeText(textVal){
            var index = textVal.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < index; i++){
                if(i % 2 == 1){
                  textVal[i].css("color","red");
                }
            }
            return $('#raspuns').text(textVal);
        }

        $('#afisare').click(function () {
            var textWrite = $('#textValue').val();
            makeText(textWrite);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set color to a specific letter. You need to add the letter in a tag and add styles in CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function makeText(textVal) {

        var index = textVal.split('');
        for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
            var span = $('<span/>');
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                span.html(textVal[i]).addClass('red');
                $('#raspuns').append(span);
            } else {
                span.html(textVal[i]).addClass('green');
                $('#raspuns').append(span);
            }
        }
        // return $('#raspuns').text(textVal);
    }

    $('#afisare').click(function () {
        var textWrite = $('#textValue').val();
        makeText(textWrite);
    });
})
```

```css
#raspuns { font-size: 20px;}
.red {
    color:red;
}
.green {
    color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Scrieti Text">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="afisare">Afisati</button>
<div id="raspuns"></div>
```

Comment: good solution, still counting the blank spaces as letters tho :p

Answer (score 2):

You can try this and this is perfectly working as checked on w3schools.com

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function makeText(textVal){
    var index = textVal.length;
    var arr='';
    for(var i = 0; i < index; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
           arr=arr+"<span style='background-color:red'>"+textVal[i]+"</span>";
        }
        else{
            arr=arr+textVal[i];
        }
    }
    $('#raspuns').html(arr);
}
$('#afisare').click(function () {
    var textWrite = $('#textValue').val();
    makeText(textWrite);
});
```

})

and html is

```
 <input type="text" id="textValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Scrieti Text">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="afisare">Afisati</button>
<div id="raspuns"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to style individual letters, each of those letters will need to be wrapped in their own HTML tag - this is necessary in order to be able to style them separately from their surrounding letters. The `<span>` tag is probably the best one to use here.

Since you can't apply the style to an individual letter directly, you'll need to change your Javascript so instead of `textVal[i].css("color","red");`, you wrap the text in a `span` and then apply the style to that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="afisare">Afisati</button>
<div id="raspuns"></div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

        function makeText(textVal){
            var index = textVal.length;
            var arr = jQuery.makeArray( textVal );

            for (var i = 0, len = textVal.length; i < len; i++) {
                 if(i % 2 == 1){
                 $('#raspuns').append('<span style="color:red">'+textVal[i]+'</span>');
                } else {
                 $('#raspuns').append('<span>'+textVal[i]+'</span>');
                }
            }
        }

        $('#afisare').click(function () {
            var textWrite = $('#textValue').val();
            makeText(textWrite);
        });
    })

</script>
```